# Use Two Monitors As One (Not Mirror, Not Extend)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've got two monitors set up.  Monitor two is currently extending my desktop area.  Both are running with a resolution of 1440x900.

What I would like to do is treat the monitors like just one super wide monitor.  Is there a way to treat it as if my desktop was 2880x900?  I just don't want it to treat the monitors as two separate screens as opposed to just one giant one.

Comment: What graphics card are you using? If you're using an ATI Radeon HD 5000 or newer, you can use Eyefinity to accomplish this

Comment: @kobaltz I'm currently using an ATI Radeon HD 4770.  Sadly not new enough :(

Comment: What OS? Most operating systems can do this easily. Eyefinity is not necessary.

Comment: @chx I'm doing this on Windows.

Comment: You can tile a window across multiple screens - is that what you need?

Comment: @lonstar : I would prefer that everything acted as if it was just one large screen.  I've been stretching windows across for the last couple of weeks but it just isn't what I want.  It doesn't give the same effect and many problems wont even allow me to do what I want with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider buying [Matrox DualHead2Go Digital](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital/)? As far as I know this device, attached between one output of your graphics card and both your monitors (both running the same resolution), will make the latter present as one screen of combined resolution - just as you want :)
There are many editions of this device (probably you should avoid buying Analog version since your resolution exceeds its capabilities). There is also TripleHead2Go with which you could use two monitors now, and later add the third if it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Both monitors are being fed essentially by separate video cards. They are two separate devices... the only way I could think to sync them up would be like that Eyefinity program @kobaltz mentions. Let's tease out the reason you are wanting to do this though. Is there a specific application you are looking to use to take advantage of, or a particular window setup you are needing?

Comment: Eyeinfinity isn't a viable option because it isn't compatible (as far as I know) with my cards series.

Comment: I understand. What it is you are trying to accomplish, and why? Is it for a single specific program?

Comment: No, I just want it that way because I prefer having a larger desktop as opposed to two individual screens/desktops.

Comment: What is the difference between you are looking to do and the extended desktop option?

Comment: Extended desktops recognizes and respects the individual screens as two desktop monitors.  If I maximize an application, it only fills the screen it's in.  I would prefer it to instead treat the two screens as one large and wide screen so if I maximize a window it should fill up both screens.  I don't want any hacks or tricks, I want native functionality.