# xrandr — Treat multiple screens as one

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

I have the same problem as this post
[Use Two Monitors As One (Not Mirror, Not Extend)](https://superuser.com/questions/445464/use-two-monitors-as-one-not-mirror-not-extend)
I also want to extend my screens to a big 3840x1200 screen rather two 1920x1200 screens and I found a solution here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214841, however, the problem I met is that I cannot find VIRTUAL1 and my xrandr result is

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
  3840x1200_60.00 (0x32f) 386.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4104 end 4512 total 5184 skew    0 clock  74.60KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1213 total 1245           clock  59.92Hz
```

So I wonder if there is a way to continue with the solution I found, or there is other solutions for this.

Thanks!

Comment: did u ever get an answer to this? all the stuff below seems not to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple monitors can be achieved in xrandr by creating a new monitor that consists out of one or more existing monitor. The virtual size of this display is automatically determined.

Take the following example were HDMI-A-0 and HDMI-A-1 are combined into one virtual display.

```
xrandr --setmonitor NameOfDisplay auto HDMI-A-0,HDMI-A-1
```

For more information on how to use setmonitor you can use the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#Combine_screens_into_virtual_display) or the [Xrandr documentation](http://www.straightrunning.com/tools/xrandr.html#sect3)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1200 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1200 --right-of VGA-0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I am using this setting, but what I want to know is like use two 1920x1200 screens as one 3840x1200 screen, so for example, when you maximum the google chrome window, it will fulfill both screens.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off left monitor command

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00
```

Turn on all monitor command

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --left-of eDP-1
```